# vuetify v-alert incorrectly dismissing sibling when transition is applied

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I am using vuetify `v-alert` with `v-for=alert in alerts` looping through `alerts` array, when an alert is dismissed @input event is fired and I'm removing it from `alerts` array.

The problem I am facing, that when the element is clicked, transition is applied, and the sibling alert is now shown at the position where the one which was dismissed, seems like the click event is fired for the sibling element as well and the sibling `v-alert` is `isVisible == false` but the @input event is not fired.

If I remove    `transition="scroll-y-reverse-transition"` from the v-alert it works properly.

Why is this happening?

```js
const alertsComponent = {
  name: "MyAlertsComponent",
  template: "#alerts",
  data() {
    return {
      alerts: []
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$root.$off("alert");
    this.$root.$on("alert", this.addAlert);
  },

  methods: {
    closeAlert(idx, alert) {
      console.log(`deleting alert idx: ${idx} - ${alert}`);
      this.$delete(this.alerts, idx);
    },

    addAlert(alert, ...args) {
      alert.type = alert.type || "error";
      this.alerts.unshift(alert);
    }
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    alertsComponent
  },

  mounted() {
    [...Array(8).keys()].forEach((e) => {
      this.fireAlert(this.counter++);
    });
  },

  methods: {
    fireAlert(val = this.counter++) {
      const alert = this.generateAlert(val);
      this.$root.$emit("alert", alert);
    },

    generateAlert(val, type = "error") {
      return {
        val,
        type
      };
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      counter: 1
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.alert-section {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <header>VueTify!</header>
        <hr>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn @click="fireAlert()">Add Alert</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <alerts-component>Hi</alerts-component>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<template id="alerts">
  <div>
    <div class="alert-section overflow-y-auto">

      <v-alert v-for="(alert, index) in alerts" :key="index" dense dismissible elevation="5" text :type="alert.type" @input="closeAlert(index, alert)" @addAlert="addAlert" 
         transition="scroll-y-reverse-transition"
         >
        {{ alert.val }}

      </v-alert>

    </div>

    <hr>
    <pre class="code">{{ JSON.stringify(alerts, null, 2) }}
    </pre>

  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is using the index as key.

If I change `:key="alert.val"` it works fine.